# How to store string which may contain multiple lines in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to assign a php value which I am getting from database to a jquery array.

For example the string may be like this:

```
a.str='I am from abc.
And my name is xyz';
```

Or:

```
b.str='I am from abc.And my name is xyz';
```

And in jquery I am assigning like this:

```
desc[dcb]=str;
```

If the string is of type b, then its not showing any error.
If the string is of type a, then its showing error like this:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiline strings in JS, so your first example would have to look something like this:

```
a.str='I am from abc.' +
      'And my name is xyz';
```

This would still produce a one-line string in JS.

---

Depending what you want to do with the string, there are two solutions:

- if you want to keep the line breaks, replace the line break with either `\n\r` or `<br />` (depending on whether you plan to use it as a plain text or inside HTML: `str_replace(PHP_EOL, '\n\r', $str);` and `str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />', $str);`)
- if you don't want to keep the line breaks, replace the line break with an empty string in PHP (`str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $str);`)

See the examples here: http://ideone.com/DjjZRt